# Unable to login due to missing access token parameter for Identity Service - iOS

Tags: connected-apps, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios, accesstoken

We have a growing number of users that are getting the following error on iOS after logging in to the connected app: "Server Error Can't connect to the server: The following required parameters the identity service were missing: access token". The app is on the SF Mobile SDK 9.2.1 and it is only happening on iOS.

The odd thing is that it seems to be device specific. If a user gets it on their device, it doesn't matter if they log out, delete the app and reinstall, restart the device, clear the browser data, or log into a different org with a different user. They always get the same error. If they use a different device, they can login fine with the same users in the same orgs. Its just that device. This below is what it is sending before it gets the error (actual values replaced with `...`):

```
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) {
    SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('testsfdc:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done#access_token=...&refresh_token=...&instance_url=...&id=...&issued_at=1652817427728&signature=...&cookie-clientSrc=...&sidCookieName=sid&cookie-sid_Client=...&scope=api+web+refresh_token&token_type=Bearer';);
} else if (window.location.replace) {
    window.location.replace('testsfdc:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done#access_token=...&refresh_token=...&instance_url=...&id=...&issued_at=1652817427728&signature=...&cookie-clientSrc=...&sidCookieName=sid&cookie-sid_Client=...&scope=api+web+refresh_token&token_type=Bearer';);
} else {
    window.location.href = 'testsfdc:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done#access_token=...&refresh_token=...&instance_url=...&id=...&issued_at=1652817427728&signature=...&cookie-clientSrc=...&sidCookieName=sid&cookie-sid_Client=...&scope=api+web+refresh_token&token_type=Bearer';
}
```

It goes into the second `if (window.location.replace)` and they gets that error. I logged in with the same user in the same org with a different device and everything above was very similar with the tokens themselves being different. I'm wondering if it is generating the access tokens incorrectly for some reason.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We spoke with Salesforce support and it turns out this is being addressed by this fix: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/commit/b0281cdfac9e0394941bc25b96bd2d4309b37da7

We are cherry picking it into the 9.2.1 SDK and so they also recommended adding the code from this PR as well: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/pull/3476/commits/ab6434723643b4632ef9682f2076e655216a6c06